# install older version of packages in webmatrix 3

Tags: asp.net, signalr, webmatrix

I need to install signalr package in my web matrix website .but when I use Nuget to add signalr to my project  get an error signalr version 2 need .net framework 4.5 but as I know webmatrix only support .net framework 4 .How can I install older version of signalr with Nuget?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following command : Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.2.0

Substitute version for the version of signalR you require, see down [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/2.0.3) the viable versions

Comment: tnx for your answer! where can I insert command in webmatrix ?

Comment: have a look at http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console

Comment: Another option is tochange the version info in Nuget config file